# Calculate reachability to a function using frama-c's value analysis

Tags: c, frama-c, abstract-interpretation

Here is my example:

```
int in;
int sum(int n){
    int log_input = n;
    int log_global = in;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int n = Frama_C_interval(-10, 10);
    in = n;
    if (n > 0){
        sum(n + 4);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I'd like to do is to find the range of the input variable n when initialized in main that results in reaching the function sum. The correct range in this example is [1, 10].

In the sample, I'd like to "save" the original input in a global value **in** and reintroduce it in the function sum by assigning it into the variable **log_global** and thus discovering the original input that resulted in reaching the function.
When running frama-c on this sample, we get that the range of log_input is [5, 14] and the range of log_global is [-10, 10]. 
I understand why this happens - the value of **in** is set at the start of **main** and is not affected by further manipulations on **n**.

I was wondering whether there is a simple way to change this in frama-c? Perhaps a simple modification in frama-c's code?

One unrelated idea I had was to manipulate the if statement in main:

```
if (in > 0){
    sum(in + 4);
}
```

I used the global variable instead of **n**. This indeed results in the right range but this solution doesn't scale well to more complicated function and deeper call stacks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution. Use the builtin `Frama_C_interval_split` and an appropriate `-slevel N` (here, at least `N=21`). The function `sum` will be examined N times, one for each possible value of N, and the result will be precise

```
int n = Frama_C_interval_split(-10, 10);
```

The results:

```
 [value] Values at end of function sum:
  log_input ∈ [5..14]
  log_global ∈ [1..10]
  __retres ∈ {0}
```

(Basically, this amounts to performing manual model-checking, so the performances won't be good for large values of N.)

Comment: I don't seem to be getting the correct results, log_input is [5, MaxInt] and log_global [MinInt, MaxInt], perhaps this is a version issue? I'm using sodium. Also if I understand correctly, this is not applicable to unknown or very large intervals, right?

Comment: My mistake, `Frama_C_interval_split` is not part of the released version. You can obtain the same result by writing a (tedious) ACSL disjunction after the call to `Frama_C_interval`: `//@ assert n == -10 | n == -9 || ... n == 10`. And indeed, this won't work well for large intervals. On the other hand, if you do not aim for full automaticity, you can do a smart partioning: `//@ assert n <= 0 || n > 0` will work in  this case.